# How to write a hex array to the device

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy

Because the device's document just let me know how to send byte-by-byte to communicate with the BLE Device.
Example: When turn on the light, the command will be

Byte 0: 0x01,
Byte 1: 0x32,
Byte 2: 0x5A,
Byte 3-4: 0x042A,
Byte 5-18: 0x0024....2A,
Byte 19-20: 0xB21F.
I saw a lot of Bluetooth API document and example. When sending a value to device, we need to use

```
await characteristic.writeValue(Uint8Array.from(data))
```

But when I try to put a  long hex buffer array like this [0x32,0x5A,0x04,0x2A,0x00,0x24,...,0x2A,0xB2,0x1F] into "data" I got an error like this:

```
NotSupportedError: GATT Error Unknown
```

But when I try a shorter command for changing some setting ([0x01,0x2a,0x58,0xab,0x00,0x1b,0xbf]) this error disappear.

So can I send a long Hex array to BLE device by Javascript code?

Sorry my English is not good and this is my first time asking in StackOverflow

Comment: Have you tried running Chrome with flags to enable low-level debugging messages about Bluetooth stuff? Apparently, this does it (taken from [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/web-bluetooth/c/TlHnA3hTksw?pli=1)):
```google-chrome --enable-logging=stderr --vmodule=*bluetooth*=9 --enable-experimental-web-platform-features```